# BroadcastReceiver loses data after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

data seems to get lost after I reboot my device or even close my app, I pass data to the BroadCastReceiver with an intent.

How I set my alarms, the user gets prompted with a DatePicker dialog

```
public void setAlarm(View view) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayDate);
    long alertTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

    alertIntent.putExtra("name", name);
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", mainId);
    alertIntent.putExtra("releaseDate", releaseDate);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, mainId, alertIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

}
```

Broadcastreceiver onReceive()

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra("releaseDate");
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

    createNotification(context, name + "releases on" + releaseDate, "Reminder", id);

  }
}
```

After I reboot my device or even close my app, the Broadcast loses its data? Instead of getting; ***Movie releases on 07/11/2015***, I get ***null releases on null***. 
The intents get deleted? (Don't know the proper term). Instead of showing a message like "THIS movie is out" , it shows instead "null is out", and it only shows one notification, no more than one, so BroadcastReceiver only reminds me about the last movie I last set a reminder to, thanks!

My Android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your app's in-memory state is lost when your process dies (which it can do at pretty much any time your app is not in the foreground). This is not unique to Android.

If you want to keep your data, you have to store it to disk in some way. You should read the official guide on storage in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks dude! So I store the name, id and release date in a  `SharedPreference` then in the onReceive() I get the data, easy enough. But there's a problem how would i know to get the data from THIS specific `SharedPreference` in the onReceive() method, maybe I could try doing that with the id, somehow? Each movie has a unique id

Comment: SharedPreferences is more suited for "settings"-type values -- where you'll have a set of known keys, and one value for each. You *could* probably get it working by using the `getAll()` method, but really, I think you'll want to use an [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: Ok thanks, do you think I can get the PendingIntent request code which is the mainId in onReceive() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621218/how-to-get-request-code-of-pendingintent-in-broadcastreceivers-onreceive?noredirect=1#comment55017363_33621218

Comment: Forgot to mark you as best answer better late than never lol ;) Happy coding!